# UnsupportedOperationException when sorting Firebase Snapshots

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to order a list fetched from Firebase using a FirebaseUI Recyclerview. The ordering depends on a average calculation that is done in the client (calculate each session's average rating). My data structure looks like this:

[image]

First, I filter all the `sessions` by the day and populate the RecyclerView. When implementing the adapter, I override `onChildrenChanged` so I can calculate the average rating of each child. Then I override `onDataChanged` when I intend to order the collection, after all averages have been calculated:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("sessions")
        .orderByChild("day")
        .equalTo(day);

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Session> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Session>()
        .setQuery(query, Session.class)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .build();

adapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(options) {
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(ChangeEventType type, DataSnapshot session, int newIndex, int oldIndex) {
        super.onChildChanged(type, session, newIndex, oldIndex);
        calculateAverageRatingOfSession(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        Collections.sort(getSnapshots(), new Comparator<Talk>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Session s1, Session s2) {
                return Float.compare(s1.getAverageRating(), s2.getAverageRating());
            }
        });
    }
};

recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the problem is that I get this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: cz.devconf2017, PID: 20094
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.set(AbstractList.java:132)
        at java.util.AbstractList$ListItr.set(AbstractList.java:426)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:247)
        at cz.devconf2017.vote.DayVotingFragment$1.onDataChanged(DayVotingFragment.java:100)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.notifyOnDataChanged(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:163)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.onDataChange(FirebaseArray.java:108)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzduz.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwu.zzbvb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxa.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I presume that `ObservableSnapshotArray` is not sortable but I cannot think of a different way to do it.

How could I workaround this exception or sort the data from the client?

Comment: That ObservableSnapshotArray is definitely read-only. If you wrap it into ArrayList, you would lose Firebase automatic updates of the list. You would need to monitor for Firebase changes manually and send updates to the adapter.